# Google Cloud Datastore API - How to Add String Array List?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to add `title` as a datastore property, where `title` is a string array. I have tried using `StringValue` and `ArrayValue`. I couldn't get the exact syntax to achieve this.

How to add string array list through Google Cloud Datastore API in Java?

```
entity = Entity.newBuilder(key)
            .set("title", getTitle())
            .build();

List<String> getTitle() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with Java Client Library for Datastore,
But I guess [`Entity.set(String name, List<? extends Value<?>> values)`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/latest/apidocs/index.html?com/google/cloud/datastore/package-summary.html) will fit your situaltion.

This `set` method accepts a list of `Value`, So your code will be like below:

```
entity = Entity.newBuilder(key)
            .set("title", convertToValueList(getTitle()))
            .build();
```

`convertToValueList` method is like this:

```
List<Value<String>> convertToValueList(List<String> list) {
    List<Value<String>> result = new List<Value<String>>();
    for (String s : list) {
        result.add(StringValue.of(s));
    }

    // FIXME: It`s better to refacter this code with Stream API.
    // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

    return result;
}
```